# Laravel command file output not updating

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I updating Laravel command file.

File code updated on server but when I run command no changes in output.

how to update Laravel command file for new changes?

Comment: Have you checked the contents of the file? Is it updated?

Comment: yes, file is up to date.